# Calculate sklearn.roc_auc_score for multi-class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, supervised-learning

I would like to calculate AUC, precision, accuracy for my classifier.
I am doing supervised learning:

Here is my working code.
This code is working fine for binary class, but not for multi class. 
Please assume that you have a dataframe with binary classes:

```
sample_features_dataframe = self._get_sample_features_dataframe()
labeled_sample_features_dataframe = retrieve_labeled_sample_dataframe(sample_features_dataframe)
labeled_sample_features_dataframe, binary_class_series, multi_class_series = self._prepare_dataframe_for_learning(labeled_sample_features_dataframe)

k = 10
k_folds = StratifiedKFold(binary_class_series, k)
for train_indexes, test_indexes in k_folds:
    train_set_dataframe = labeled_sample_features_dataframe.loc[train_indexes.tolist()]
    test_set_dataframe = labeled_sample_features_dataframe.loc[test_indexes.tolist()]

    train_class = binary_class_series[train_indexes]
    test_class = binary_class_series[test_indexes]
    selected_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    selected_classifier.fit(train_set_dataframe, train_class)
    predictions = selected_classifier.predict(test_set_dataframe)
    predictions_proba = selected_classifier.predict_proba(test_set_dataframe)

    roc += roc_auc_score(test_class, predictions_proba[:,1])
    accuracy += accuracy_score(test_class, predictions)
    recall += recall_score(test_class, predictions)
    precision += precision_score(test_class, predictions)
```

In the end I divided the results in K of course for getting average AUC, precision, etc. 
This code is working fine. 
However, I cannot calculate the same for multi class:

```
    train_class = multi_class_series[train_indexes]
    test_class = multi_class_series[test_indexes]

    selected_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    selected_classifier.fit(train_set_dataframe, train_class)

    predictions = selected_classifier.predict(test_set_dataframe)
    predictions_proba = selected_classifier.predict_proba(test_set_dataframe)
```

I found that for multi class I have to add the parameter "weighted" for average.

```
    roc += roc_auc_score(test_class, predictions_proba[:,1], average="weighted")
```

I got an error: raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))

ValueError: multiclass format is not supported

Answer (score 15):

You can't use `roc_auc` as a single summary metric for multiclass models. If you want, you could calculate per-class `roc_auc`, as

```
roc = {label: [] for label in multi_class_series.unique()}
for label in multi_class_series.unique():
    selected_classifier.fit(train_set_dataframe, train_class == label)
    predictions_proba = selected_classifier.predict_proba(test_set_dataframe)
    roc[label] += roc_auc_score(test_class, predictions_proba[:,1])
```

However it's more usual to use `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix` to evaluate the performance of a multiclass model.

Comment: Thank you for your very wise final advice!

Comment: Note that it _is_ possible to compute a single AUROC metric for a multiclass model by simply averaging the AUROC for the individual classes (or using some other reasonable metric aggregation strategy)

Answer (score 13):

If you are looking for something relatively simple that takes in the actual and predicted lists and returns a dictionary with all the classes as keys and its roc_auc_score as values, you can use the following method:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

def roc_auc_score_multiclass(actual_class, pred_class, average = "macro"):

  #creating a set of all the unique classes using the actual class list
  unique_class = set(actual_class)
  roc_auc_dict = {}
  for per_class in unique_class:
    #creating a list of all the classes except the current class 
    other_class = [x for x in unique_class if x != per_class]

    #marking the current class as 1 and all other classes as 0
    new_actual_class = [0 if x in other_class else 1 for x in actual_class]
    new_pred_class = [0 if x in other_class else 1 for x in pred_class]

    #using the sklearn metrics method to calculate the roc_auc_score
    roc_auc = roc_auc_score(new_actual_class, new_pred_class, average = average)
    roc_auc_dict[per_class] = roc_auc

  return roc_auc_dict

print("\nLogistic Regression")
# assuming your already have a list of actual_class and predicted_class from the logistic regression classifier
lr_roc_auc_multiclass = roc_auc_score_multiclass(actual_class, predicted_class)
print(lr_roc_auc_multiclass)

# Sample output
# Logistic Regression
# {0: 0.5087457159427196, 1: 0.5, 2: 0.5, 3: 0.5114706737345112, 4: 0.5192307692307693}
# 0.5078894317816
```

Comment: are you binarizing the output and then calculating the ROC for each class in one vs all ?

Comment: Yes! That's what is done after the comment `#marking the current class as 1 and all other classes as 0`

Answer (score 11):

The `average` option of `roc_auc_score` is only defined for multilabel problems.

You can take a look at the following example from the scikit-learn documentation to define you own micro- or macro-averaged scores for multiclass problems:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#multiclass-settings

*Edit*: there is an issue on the scikit-learn tracker to implement ROC AUC for multiclass problems: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3298

Comment: No, I think the `average` parameter works just fine for multiclass

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in here, to the best of my knowledge there is not yet a way to easily compute roc auc for multiple class settings natively in sklearn.

However, if you are familiar with `classification_report` you may like this simple implementation that returns the same output as `classification_report` as a `pandas.DataFrame` which I personally found it very handy!:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import interp

from  sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

def class_report(y_true, y_pred, y_score=None, average='micro'):
    if y_true.shape != y_pred.shape:
        print("Error! y_true %s is not the same shape as y_pred %s" % (
              y_true.shape,
              y_pred.shape)
        )
        return

    lb = LabelBinarizer()

    if len(y_true.shape) == 1:
        lb.fit(y_true)

    #Value counts of predictions
    labels, cnt = np.unique(
        y_pred,
        return_counts=True)
    n_classes = len(labels)
    pred_cnt = pd.Series(cnt, index=labels)

    metrics_summary = precision_recall_fscore_support(
            y_true=y_true,
            y_pred=y_pred,
            labels=labels)

    avg = list(precision_recall_fscore_support(
            y_true=y_true, 
            y_pred=y_pred,
            average='weighted'))

    metrics_sum_index = ['precision', 'recall', 'f1-score', 'support']
    class_report_df = pd.DataFrame(
        list(metrics_summary),
        index=metrics_sum_index,
        columns=labels)

    support = class_report_df.loc['support']
    total = support.sum() 
    class_report_df['avg / total'] = avg[:-1] + [total]

    class_report_df = class_report_df.T
    class_report_df['pred'] = pred_cnt
    class_report_df['pred'].iloc[-1] = total

    if not (y_score is None):
        fpr = dict()
        tpr = dict()
        roc_auc = dict()
        for label_it, label in enumerate(labels):
            fpr[label], tpr[label], _ = roc_curve(
                (y_true == label).astype(int), 
                y_score[:, label_it])

            roc_auc[label] = auc(fpr[label], tpr[label])

        if average == 'micro':
            if n_classes <= 2:
                fpr["avg / total"], tpr["avg / total"], _ = roc_curve(
                    lb.transform(y_true).ravel(), 
                    y_score[:, 1].ravel())
            else:
                fpr["avg / total"], tpr["avg / total"], _ = roc_curve(
                        lb.transform(y_true).ravel(), 
                        y_score.ravel())

            roc_auc["avg / total"] = auc(
                fpr["avg / total"], 
                tpr["avg / total"])

        elif average == 'macro':
            # First aggregate all false positive rates
            all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([
                fpr[i] for i in labels]
            ))

            # Then interpolate all ROC curves at this points
            mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
            for i in labels:
                mean_tpr += interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])

            # Finally average it and compute AUC
            mean_tpr /= n_classes

            fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
            tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr

            roc_auc["avg / total"] = auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])

        class_report_df['AUC'] = pd.Series(roc_auc)

    return class_report_df
```

Here is some example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=5000, n_features=10,
                           n_informative=5, n_redundant=0,
                           n_classes=10, random_state=0, 
                           shuffle=False)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Regular `classification_report`:

```
sk_report = classification_report(
    digits=6,
    y_true=y_test, 
    y_pred=model.predict(X_test))
print(sk_report)
```

Out:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0   0.262774  0.553846  0.356436       130
          1   0.405405  0.333333  0.365854       135
          2   0.367347  0.150000  0.213018       120
          3   0.350993  0.424000  0.384058       125
          4   0.379310  0.447154  0.410448       123
          5   0.525000  0.182609  0.270968       115
          6   0.362573  0.488189  0.416107       127
          7   0.330189  0.299145  0.313901       117
          8   0.328571  0.407080  0.363636       113
          9   0.571429  0.248276  0.346154       145

avg / total   0.390833  0.354400  0.345438      1250
```

Custom classification_report:

```
report_with_auc = class_report(
    y_true=y_test, 
    y_pred=model.predict(X_test), 
    y_score=model.predict_proba(X_test))

print(report_with_auc)
```

Out:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score  support    pred       AUC
0             0.262774  0.553846  0.356436    130.0   274.0  0.766477
1             0.405405  0.333333  0.365854    135.0   111.0  0.773974
2             0.367347  0.150000  0.213018    120.0    49.0  0.817341
3             0.350993  0.424000  0.384058    125.0   151.0  0.803364
4             0.379310  0.447154  0.410448    123.0   145.0  0.802436
5             0.525000  0.182609  0.270968    115.0    40.0  0.680870
6             0.362573  0.488189  0.416107    127.0   171.0  0.855768
7             0.330189  0.299145  0.313901    117.0   106.0  0.766526
8             0.328571  0.407080  0.363636    113.0   140.0  0.754812
9             0.571429  0.248276  0.346154    145.0    63.0  0.769100
avg / total   0.390833  0.354400  0.345438   1250.0  1250.0  0.776071
```

Comment: I like the easy to read format of the generated output. Thanks

Comment: @Raul I was using your method and realized it does not show classes that were not listed in the y_pred list. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 4):

I needed to do the same (roc_auc_score for multiclass). Following the last phrase of the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39703870/7434560), I have searched and found that sklearn does provide auc_roc_score for multiclass in version 0.22.1.(I had a previous version and after updating to this version I could get the auc_roc_score multiclass functionality as mentioned at [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score))

MWE example (for a batch of examples equal to 16):

```
final_preds = torch.softmax(preds,dim=1).squeeze(1)
num_classes = final_preds.shape[1]
print("y_true={}".format(y))
print("y_score={}".format(final_preds))
labels1 = np.arange(num_classes)
print("roc_auc_score={}".format(roc_auc_score(y.detach().cpu().numpy(),final_preds.detach().cpu().numpy(), average='macro', multi_class='ovo',labels=labels1)))
```

will produce:

```
y_true=tensor([5, 5, 4, 0, 6, 0, 4, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0])
y_score=tensor([[0.0578, 0.0697, 0.1135, 0.1264, 0.0956, 0.1534, 0.1391, 0.0828, 0.0725,
     0.0891],
    [0.0736, 0.0892, 0.1096, 0.1277, 0.0888, 0.1372, 0.1227, 0.0895, 0.0914,
     0.0702],
    [0.0568, 0.1571, 0.0339, 0.1200, 0.1069, 0.1800, 0.1285, 0.0486, 0.0961,
     0.0720],
    [0.1649, 0.0876, 0.1051, 0.0768, 0.0498, 0.0838, 0.0676, 0.0601, 0.1900,
     0.1143],
    [0.1096, 0.0797, 0.0580, 0.1190, 0.2201, 0.1036, 0.0550, 0.0514, 0.1018,
     0.1018],
    [0.1522, 0.1033, 0.1139, 0.0789, 0.0496, 0.0553, 0.0730, 0.1428, 0.1447,
     0.0863],
    [0.1416, 0.1304, 0.1184, 0.0775, 0.0683, 0.0657, 0.1521, 0.0426, 0.1342,
     0.0693],
    [0.0944, 0.0806, 0.0622, 0.0629, 0.0652, 0.0936, 0.0607, 0.1270, 0.2392,
     0.1142],
    [0.0848, 0.0966, 0.0923, 0.1301, 0.0932, 0.0910, 0.1066, 0.0877, 0.1297,
     0.0880],
    [0.1040, 0.1341, 0.0906, 0.0934, 0.0586, 0.0949, 0.0869, 0.1605, 0.0819,
     0.0952],
    [0.2882, 0.0716, 0.1136, 0.0235, 0.0022, 0.0170, 0.0891, 0.2371, 0.0533,
     0.1044],
    [0.2274, 0.1077, 0.1183, 0.0937, 0.0140, 0.0705, 0.1168, 0.0913, 0.1120,
     0.0483],
    [0.0846, 0.1281, 0.0772, 0.1088, 0.1333, 0.0831, 0.0444, 0.1553, 0.1285,
     0.0568],
    [0.0756, 0.0822, 0.1468, 0.1286, 0.0749, 0.0978, 0.0565, 0.1513, 0.0840,
     0.1023],
    [0.0521, 0.0555, 0.1031, 0.0816, 0.1145, 0.1090, 0.1095, 0.0846, 0.0919,
     0.1982],
    [0.0491, 0.1814, 0.0331, 0.0052, 0.0166, 0.0051, 0.0812, 0.0045, 0.5111,
     0.1127]])
roc_auc_score=0.40178571428571425
```

To make it work, I had to softmax the prediction score to ensure that the scores for each sample are probability summing to 1 (sum(y_score[:,i])=1 for all i in batch_size). The second was passing the labels1 parameters to allow the multi_class version of roc_auc understand the number of all classes (in the other case y_true should have all available classes (that is not most of the times the case)).

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of metrics which can be used to quantify the quality of a multiclass classifier including `roc_auc_score`. Go through this link below to know more.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter

Actually roc_auc is computed for a binary classifier though the `roc_auc_score` function implements a 'onevsrest' or 'onevsone' strategy to convert a multi-class classification problem into a N or [image] binary problems respectively.

To only compute area under the curve (AUC) set `multi_class` parameter to either 'ovr' or 'ovo'.

> `roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, multi_class='ovr')`

here `y_score` can be output of `clf.decision_function()` or `clf.predict_proba()` functions.
However, to plot ROC curve for a binary classifier, first implement `OneVsRestClassifier()` or `OneVsOneClassifier` and then use the output of `clf.decision_function()` or `clf.predict_proba()` functions to plot `roc_curve` or `precision_recall_curve` depending upon you data. Visit the first link sggested by [ogrisel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685740/calculate-sklearn-roc-auc-score-for-multi-class/39703870#39703870)

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#multiclass-settings

Answer (score 0):

Updating on maxymoo's answer.

roc[label] += roc_auc_score(test_class, predictions_proba[:,label])

or refer to classifier.classes_ attribute to decide the right column for interested label.

Answer (score 0):

@Raul your function looks good but there is a problem in the function when it calculates the roc_score for micro average with n_classes<=2. I was having issues with the dimensions so I changed the following:

from this

```
if average == 'micro':
        if n_classes <= 2:
            fpr["avg / total"], tpr["avg / total"], _ = roc_curve(
                lb.transform(y_true).ravel(), 
                **y_score[:, 1]**.ravel())
```

to this

```
if average == 'micro':
        if n_classes <= 2:
            fpr["avg / total"], tpr["avg / total"], _ = roc_curve(
                lb.transform(y_true).ravel(), 
                **y_score**.ravel())
```

I hope this change does not create problems in the calculation of roc_score.