# sklearn roc_auc_score with multi_class=="ovr" should have None average available

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, auc

I'm trying to compute the AUC score for a multiclass problem using the sklearn's [roc_auc_score()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score) function.

I have prediction matrix of shape [n_samples,n_classes] and a ground truth vector of shape [n_samples], named `np_pred` and `np_label` respectively.

What I'm trying to achieve is the set of AUC scores, one for each classes that I have.

To do so I would like to use the `average` parameter option `None` and `multi_class` parameter set to `"ovr"`, but if I run

```
roc_auc_score(y_score=np_pred, y_true=np_label, multi_class="ovr",average=None)
```

I get back

```
ValueError: average must be one of ('macro', 'weighted') for multiclass problems
```

This error is expected from the sklearn function in the case of the [multiclass](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c42d54b26137a456c510c5fdba1ba23e0/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L446); but if you take a look at the `roc_auc_score` function source code, you can see that if the `multi_class` parameter is set to `"ovr"`, and the average is one of the accepted one, the multiClass case is treated as a [multiLabel one](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c42d54b26137a456c510c5fdba1ba23e0/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L491) and the internal multiLabel function [accepts `None`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/e947689c90624009ea25f4f97f7b6cb0198a96dc/sklearn/metrics/_base.py#L67) as `average` parameter.

So, by looking at the code, it seems that I should be able to execute a multiclass with a `None` average in a `One vs Rest` case but the `if`s in the source code do not allow such combination.

Am I wrong?

In case I'm wrong, from a theoretical point of view should I fake a multilabel case just to have the different AUCs for the different classes or should I write my own function that cycles the different classes and outputs the AUCs?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already know, right now `sklearn` multiclass ROC AUC only handles the `macro` and `weighted` averages. But it can be implemented as it can then individually return the scores for each class.

Theoretically speaking, you could implement `OVR` and calculate per-class `roc_auc_score`, as:

```
roc = {label: [] for label in multi_class_series.unique()}
for label in multi_class_series.unique():
    selected_classifier.fit(train_set_dataframe, train_class == label)
    predictions_proba = selected_classifier.predict_proba(test_set_dataframe)
    roc[label] += roc_auc_score(test_class, predictions_proba[:,1])
```

Comment: Right now this is the same solution that I've decided to use. I wish that the multiclass ROC AUC from `sklearn` implemented this functionality because it seems just around the corner but unreachable.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693007/12508712) is the link to the original copy pasted code

Answer (score 11):

According to sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html), the default parameter for multi_class is 'raised', In documentation it is mentioned, that the default parameter will throw an exception, so you have to mention `ovr` or `ovo` explicitly `multi_class='ovr'`.

Refer to the attached screenshot

[image: Mention Explicitly of ovr or ovo, rather than using default value]