# roc_auc_score for multiclass classification, AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, multiclass-classification

I have a pipeline with RandomForestRegressor as an estimator. (You don't have to check the pipeline, it works fine for any estimator).

The target contains 5 classes and I want to compute `roc_auc_score`. After reading the Sklearn [user guide on the function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multi-class-case), I learned that to compute ROC AUC for each class, you have to use the following syntax:

```
# Compute roc_auc for class 0
roc_auc_score(
    y_test,
    pipeline.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 0],
    multi_class="ovr",
    average="macro",
)
```

But this is giving me this error:

```
AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61288972/axiserror-axis-1-is-out-of-bounds-for-array-of-dimension-1-when-calculating-auc) but that thread didn't help. What worked was when I changed the above code to this:

```
# Remove the class subsetting
roc_auc_score(
    y_test,
    logreg_pipeline.predict_proba(X_test),
    multi_class="ovr",
    average="macro",
)
```

Instead of specifying the first class with `[:, 0]`, I passed the whole numpy array you get from `predict_proba` and it returned a score of 0.92. Should I suppose that this score is the macro average for all 5 class's roc_auc?

P.S. the target is not encoded and since, there are 5 classes in the target, predict_proba is returning a numpy array with 5 columns

Comment: Please do not use the comments for adding info - edit & update your post instead.

Comment: Is `y_test` an array of shape `(N, 5)`?

Comment: @ArturoSbr No. But what I am getting from `predict_proba` is

Comment: Also, what is the shape of `y_train`?

Comment: @ArturoSbr `(36139, )`. It is a 1D array, flattened