# How to implement Grid search cv with multi output classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, gridsearchcv

I am working on a dataset and have to make two predictions,i.e 2 columns of y and each column is also multiclass.
So,I am using XGBoost with MultiOutput Classfier and to tune it I want to use Grid Search CV.

```
xgb_clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.1,
                n_estimators=3000,
                max_depth=3,
                min_child_weight=1,
                subsample=0.8,
                colsample_bytree=0.8,
                objective='multi:softmax',
                nthread=4,
                num_class=9,
                seed=27
                )
model = MultiOutputClassifier(estimator=xgb_clf)
    param_test1 = { 'estimator__max_depth':[3],'estimator__min_child_weight':[4]}
gsearch1 = GridSearchCV(estimator =model, 
 param_grid = param_test1, scoring='roc_auc',n_jobs=4,iid=False, cv=5)
gsearch1.fit(X_train_split,y_train_split)
gsearch1.grid_scores_, gsearch1.best_params_, gsearch1.best_score_
```

But when i do so I get a error

```
_RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)
_RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 431, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 285, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 595, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 253, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 253, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 544, in _fit_and_score
    test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 591, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 87, in __call__
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 300, in _score
    raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: multiclass-multioutput format is not supported
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-e53fdaaedf6b> in <module>()
      5 gsearch1 = GridSearchCV(estimator =model, 
      6  param_grid = param_test1, scoring='roc_auc',n_jobs=4,iid=False, cv=5)
----> 7 gsearch1.fit(X_train_split,y_train_split)
      8 gsearch1.grid_scores_, gsearch1.best_params_, gsearch1.best_score_

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    708                 return results
    709 
--> 710             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    711 
    712         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1149     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1150         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1151         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1152 
   1153 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    687                                for parameters, (train, test)
    688                                in product(candidate_params,
--> 689                                           cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    690 
    691                 if len(out) < 1:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1040 
   1041             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1042                 self.retrieve()
   1043             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
   1044             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    919             try:
    920                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 921                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    922                 else:
    923                     self._output.extend(job.get())

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    540         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    541         try:
--> 542             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    543         except CfTimeoutError as e:
    544             raise TimeoutError from e

/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    430                 raise CancelledError()
    431             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 432                 return self.__get_result()
    433             else:
    434                 raise TimeoutError()

/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

ValueError: multiclass-multioutput format is not supported
```

I think the error occurs as I am using roc_auc as my scoring method but I don't know how to fix it. Should I use any other scoring method?

Comment: Please edit and add more context to your question: which technology, platform and runtime environment you are using, what is the problem that you are solving. Also, please specify what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you think right. The issue is coming from the fact that ROC AUC score is valid for binary classification case. Instead you can use the average of ROC AUC scores across all classes.

```
# from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685740/calculate-sklearn-roc-auc-score-for-multi-class
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import numpy as np

def roc_auc_score_multiclass(actual_class, pred_class, average = "macro"):

  #creating a set of all the unique classes using the actual class list
  unique_class = set(actual_class)
  roc_auc_dict = {}
  for per_class in unique_class:
    #creating a list of all the classes except the current class 
    other_class = [x for x in unique_class if x != per_class]

    #marking the current class as 1 and all other classes as 0
    new_actual_class = [0 if x in other_class else 1 for x in actual_class]
    new_pred_class = [0 if x in other_class else 1 for x in pred_class]

    #using the sklearn metrics method to calculate the roc_auc_score
    roc_auc = roc_auc_score(new_actual_class, new_pred_class, average = average)
    roc_auc_dict[per_class] = roc_auc

  return np.mean([x for x in roc_auc_dict.values()])
```

Using this function you can get the ROC AUC score for each class against all others. Then you can take the mean of that values and use it as a scorer. You might need to convert you function to scorer object using `make_scorer` function (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html).

Comment: my problem is not multiclass. My problem is i have multi output, i.e two columns of y are predicted by my model. So, i need to evaluate them.

Comment: yep, so the provided function does which you want, it receives 2 arrays and calculates the ROC AUCs and calculates the average of all ROC AUCs/